# Can I add primary key contrains in sql table after creation or during export of dataframe to sql table

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate, pandasql

I would like to import my Excel data to a database in SQL using pd.read_sql function. Here I tried using `flask sqlalchemy`. I cannot create my table and only can Transfer data from Excel to SQL because my Excel file has more than 1000 columns. Based on the reaseach I did, now I thought of using Flask migrate Option to do the changes after creation using the functions like `flask db migrate` and `flask db upgrade`. But no success. I need key contraints to implement relationship between tables after creation or during the export of my dataframe to SQL function.

This code here, is for database and table creation :

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
#from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
#from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df= pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\z103684\Desktop\new_data.xlsx',sep=';')

df1=df.loc[:, (df != 0).any(axis=0)]
X1 = df1.iloc[0:,0:]
dataset = X1.astype('float32')
dataset['date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', periods=len(dataset), freq='D')
dataset=dataset.set_index('date')

dataset.columns = dataset.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace('[', '').str.replace('.', '').str.replace(']','')

dff= pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\z103684\Desktop\one_column.xlsx',sep=';')

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///Measurements.db')

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///Measurements.db'
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

class table1(db.Model):
    __tablename__='table1'
    dataset.to_sql(con=engine, name='table1', if_exists='replace')
    table1.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')

class table2(db.Model):
    __tablename__='table2'
    dff.to_sql(con=engine,name='table2',if_exists='replace')
    table2.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id1')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello flask"

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Please check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I would start from beginning - first create in database tables with all columns and later create code which imports all neede data in correct way - without using `read_sql`.

Comment: GTW: If you add new column which can't use `NULL` then you have to define default value - to add this value to all rows.

Comment: To start from beginning. but i have many csv's and excel with more than 350 columns in each. so i used this read_sql

Comment: No you can't...